# crash when returning an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm getting a crash because my array is deallocated, but I don't know why or where. The array comes from something that looks like this:

```
@implementation Sources

- (NSArray *)sourceArray{
   NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
   //fill array with objects
   return (NSArray*)array;
}

@end
```

Then, in a tableview, I have a property where I override the getter like so:

```
- (NSArray *)feedSourceList 
{
    if (!_sources) {    
       _feedSourceList = [_sourceList sourceArray];
    }
    return _sources;
}
```

And then I call the property like this, and this causes a crash:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.feedSourceList count];
}
```

I don't know why the array is being deallocated. Is it's autorelease pool being drained somewhere I'm not aware of? What's the proper way of retaining this array?

Comment: BTW, no need to cast here: `return (NSArray*)array;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your getter should look like this:

```
- (NSArray *)feedSourceList 
{
    if (!_sources) {    
       _sources = [[_sourceList sourceArray] retain];
    }
    return _sources;
}
```

The returned `NSArray` from `-sourceArray` is **autoreleased**, so that is being deallocated when the `NSAutoreleasePool` drains. You need to take ownership of the returned object by invoking `-retain`.

Comment: Note that such a pattern does have fragility.  Namely, you are changing state within the getter and, thus, an observer may not see the change or may see the change during a phase of execution that can't deal with the fact that the change happened while a getter was getting.   Generally, this style of lazy initialization is often best to be avoided.

Comment: So a better solution would be to initialize the sources array in the init array? That is, make it not lazy?